# Thailand Krabi airport - souvenir shops assortment

Tags: thailand, krabi, kbv

From [What to Expect on Arrival and Leaving Krabi Airport](http://www.krabi-hotels.com/info/krabi-airport.htm):

> Krabi Airport has all the facilities required to travel comfortably:
>   ATM machines, money exchange booths, books and souvenir shops, and a
>   few venues that sell food and drinks

From [Shopping & Eating at Krabi Airport](http://asia-airports.com/thailand/kbv/shopping.php):

> As a small airport, Krabi doesn't have a lot in the way of shopping or
>   dining opportunities.

Do souvenir shops sell edible insects or other exotic Thailand food/drinks in Krabi airport? What are options to buy before departing? Are prices significantly higher than in a city?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Krabi airport has two terminals, I presume you're referring to the international one.

As of January 2017, the fresh food selection once past security & immigration when departing is limited to a cafe. I can't claim to recall its menu in detail, but the offerings were overpriced and bland, certainly no edible insects in sight (and this is not a thing you really see outside street food/night markets anyway).

There are also a bunch of souvenir shops selling dried mangoes, cans of Pringles etc, with 200-300% markups.  I specifically recall the same bag of dried mango that's around 250 baht at the supermarket being hawked for 600.